# Zend A plugin by the name "Produit\Segment" was not found in the plugin manager Zend\Router\RoutePluginManager'

Tags: zend-framework, plugins

I'm new with Zend, and i followed the Zend tutorial. I've seen people had this error as well, but the solution doesn't work for me. They say to add "use Zend[...]\Segment" but I already did..

I'm working with 'Produit' and not 'Album', but works the same.

Here is my Produit's **module.config.php**

```
<?php

namespace Produit;

use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [

'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'produit' => [
            'type'    => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/produit[/:action[/:id]]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\ProduitController::class,
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],

'view_manager' => [
    'template_path_stack' => [
        'produit' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ],
],
];
```

Here is my Application's **module.config.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'Zend\Session',
    'Zend\Form',
    'Zend\Db',
    'Zend\Router',
    'Zend\Validator',
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'Produit',
];
```

And here is my **ProduitController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Produit\Controller;


use Produit\Model\ProduitTable;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class ProduitController extends AbstractActionController
{

private $table;

public function __construct(ProduitTable $table)
{
    $this->table = $table;
}
public function indexAction()
{
    return new ViewModel([
        'produit' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
    ]);
}

public function addAction()
{
}

public function editAction()
{
}

public function deleteAction()
{
}
}
```

If you need something else, just tell me i'll give it to you !
Thank you

Comment: Where is the error coming from? There is no reference to `Album` in the code you've posted.

Comment: Mb on this, the error is from 'Produit/Segment' and not 'Album/Segment'

Comment: Well, the code you've posted does not seem to match the error message, so something's off somewhere.